# TypeError: unable to create data property ~ React ~ ESLint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, static-analysis, static-code-analysis

When working with ESLint on some React components I'm getting a type error which terminates the ESLint with the message `TypeError: unable to create data property. Occurred while linting PATH/TO/MY/REACT/COMPONENT/mycomponent.js.jsx:54`.

The code looks like that:

```
class MyComponentextends React.Component {
  ... // Some component's logic.
}
// MyComponent.defaultProps is the line 54 to which the errors points out.
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  property1: null,
  loading: true,
  property1: [],
  property2: null
}
```

The error repeats in every file where `ANY_COMPONENT.defaultProps` is declared, but can't find the explanation why it is that. The project is in React `15.6.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you problem is probably the duplicate property1:

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  property1: null, // remove this one
  loading: true,
  property1: [], // or this one
  property2: null
}
```

Also a great way to debug lint rules is to set the ignore rule flag -> see the name of the rule and try to figure out what it is doing (some rules are too restrictive and maybe not a good fit for your project).